# Scan USB and auto start of an app

Tags: c++, qt

I have wrote an application in QT/C++ on MacOS .

The application is just an agent which check if a usb device is connected. If yes, an application is started.

The code of "LaunchAgent.app" is done as below to detect and start:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    UsbDetection *MyUSBDevice = new UsbDetection;

    if(MyUSBDevice->isConnected() == true) {
        QString agentExecutableDirPath = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
    QString fileBrowserExecutablePath = agentExecutableDirPath + "/../../../../MacOS/connect";

        QProcess *process = new QProcess();
        process->start(fileBrowserExecutablePath);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried to replace the path by :
        QString fileBrowserExecutablePath = agentExecutableDirPath + "/../../../../../../connect.app";

This agent "LaunchAgent.app" is currently stored inside the application package "connect.app". The application package is named "connect.app" and contain:

```
connect.app/
    Contents/
        Frameworks/
        MacOS/
            connect
        Plugins/
        Resources/
            LaunchAgent.app
```

Any idea, why once the LaunchAgent.app is started, device connected, the connect.app is not started.

The app seems trying to launch because the app also create a log file. connect.app create his log file but it's empty such as the app start but is killed right after. perhaps the use of process->start is not the best choice

Thanks

Comment: What is `UsbDetection` and where is it coming from? Are you sure that it is working correctly (for example by tracing that the device is found) and that the Qt code is the faulty part? Also have you printed and verified the path of the connect.app when you are trying to launch it?

Comment: @Rudolfs UsbDetection is a custom piece of code. I have already tried it and it works. UsbDetection, just checking if a specific usb id is connected and return true if yes.

Comment: Can you try checking `QProcess::error()` after you call `start()` to see what exactly is going wrong?